# Python Interactive Window keeps opening a script instead or running it

Tags: python

I keep trying to run this loop, which is meant to register numbers above or below 50 in a random set of 10 loops.

```
import random, string
N = random.sample(range(1,100),10)
if N > 50
        cntOver += 1
if N <= 50
        cntUnder += 1
cntOver = 0; cntUnder = 0
print cntOver, cntUnder
```

I'm not sure if I wrote something wrong with it, but every time I try to run it with Python's interactive window, it just opens up the script file instead of running it. I admit I am a complete novice here, so if the solution is simple don't be afraid to call me dim.

Comment: To clarify: Does it only do this for this particular script all to anything you try to run?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it does do it for most anything I try

Answer (score 1):

1. N is a list, so you can not compare N with 50. You should use a for-loop.
2. You should initialize cntOver and cntUnder first.
   Therefore, the correct way is following:

```
import random, string
N = random.sample(range(1,100),10)
cntOver = 0; cntUnder = 0
for i in N:
    if i > 50:
        cntOver += 1
    if i <= 50:
        cntUnder += 1
print (cntOver, cntUnder)
```

The better way is using the built-in function sum(), where we can use list as an input.
check how to use it: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp

```
import random, string
N = random.sample(range(1,100),10)
cntOver = sum(i > 50 for i in N)
cntUnder = sum(i <= 50 for i in N)
print (cntOver, cntUnder)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, the class we went over loops wasn't the best for me, and the textbook wasn't very clear on this. Thanks to COVID it's all online so asking a classmate for advice is not do-able.

Comment: You can learn more basic thing in w3school. For example, how the for-loop works. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp